# How do I map using spring JPA(Hibernate) for several tables referring to one table based on type and id?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, polymorphic-associations

I have a legacy database design where Table A, B, C has id as primary key and they all have one to many relationship to table D. Table D has linkable_type and linkable_id as join criteria to these table i.e. A, B,C.

where D.linkable_type ='A' and D.linkable_id = A.id

Similarly for other tables as well it is joined as
D.linkable_type ='B' and D.linkable_id = B.id
D.linkable_type ='C' and D.linkable_id = C.id

I have tried

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="LINKABLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
@WhereJoinTable(clause = " LINKABLE_TYPE = 'A' ")
private A a;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TrainRoute
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="LINKABLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
@WhereJoinTable(clause = " LINKABLE_TYPE = 'B' ")
private B b;
```

But it doesn't work due to multiple join on same column.
I have also tried

```
@ManyToOne
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "LINKABLE_TYPE"))
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = A.class, value = "A"),
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = B.class, value = "B"),
                @MetaValue(targetEntity = C.class, value = "C")
        })
@Cascade( { org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "LINKABLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@JsonProperty("linkable_id")
private E e;
```

I created

```
    public interface E {}
```

and implemented in child classes A,B,C, But this doesn't allow to include @oneToMany in inverse relationship within class A where Class can contain list of D. it doesn't find anything and fails.

```
      @OneToMany
      private List<D> d;
```

Can anyone help me how shall i map these relationship in Spring JPA using Hibernate?

Comment: try Eslipselink conceptions (i.e. not standard JPA) with keyword mulitenant

Comment: Can you elaborate more with some example?

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant ... I'm not sure this is EXACTLY You want, but read

Answer (score 0):

We solved this with following approach:
We made the @OneToMany Object as @Transient and save that object manually after the parent object was saved. This way we had the both the keys available for mapping.

In fetch part we could utilise JPQL on both columns.